# Actualizar un registro si no existe o si

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

¿Cómo puedo verificar si existe el registro para después actualizarlo si no existe que lo inserte?

Intenté con esto, pero no me deja.

```
UPDATE tienda SET Campo1 = 'carro' WHERE ID = '123'
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
INSERT INTO tienda VALUES ('coche','123')
```

incluso con este query

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM tienda WHERE ID = '123')
UPDATE tienda SET Campo1 = 'carro' WHERE ID = '123'
ELSE
INSERT INTO tienda VALUES ('coche','123')
```

es un ejemplo, ese es el formato que utilicé, estoy usando mysql

Comment: Pues tienes el [on duplicate key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) si el control de duplicados es por clave primaria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es la sentencia [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO tienda  VALUES ('coche', '123') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE campo1 = 'coche'
```

Comment: +1 buena respuesta!

Comment: gracias amigo me ayudaste mucho!